# Moving a Local mySQL database from Laravel/Homestead to live site database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, homestead

I'm new here so sorry if this is posted in the wrong place >.<

I recently started using CraftCMS and decided to make a site with it. After looking at multiple forums about development I decided to use Laravel/Homestead to develop the site locally. It's working great! Everything is working fine, all the data is being saved and it works every time I boot up homestead.

The one question I have is how to move all this data from my local database to a live site. I have Bluehost and I know it's capable of mySQL and hosting a CraftCMS site. I just need to know how to transfer all the data.

I've been using Sequel Pro to monitor everything locally. So I feel like it's possible. Not really experienced with databases in this way. Just need a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you access to your Bluehost DB in Sequel Pro? If you can, I think you should first go to your local homestead DB and click [File]->[Export]. And go to Bluehost DB and click [File]->[Import]. Remember to choose the same format as you exported.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.

If you can export your craft db with sequel pro (or the command line)

Assuming your local database env is root with

`mysqldump -u root -p password mycraftdb > dump.sql`

You'll need to import this sql file in phpmyadmin on bluehost
Here's a help doc. https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/256

Start a new database unless you're using the old tables in your new local craft site.  Definitely back up your old one.

Whenever you work with a host like Bluehost, godaddy, etc. You're going to have an obnoxious time trying to get everything configured to pass the system report for craftcms.  Sometimes you'll even have to reach out to the host to do something simple like upping a memory_limit.

Here's an article my friend wrote about his experiences using craftcms with these hosting environments. It could be helpful.

https://medium.com/@importantcoding/craftcms-how-i-hate-to-love-you-e0d26722a1d2